# Flutter: Stream broadcast being called more than once

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm building a quiz where when a question is answered, Stream does the following:

```
 final streamController = StreamController.broadcast(sync: true);

 streamController.add("correct"); or  streamController.add("wrong");
```

And so another screen hears that warning and performs some other tasks.

```
streamController.stream.listen((event) {
                          if (event == "correct") {
                            print("correct");
                          });
```

The only problem is that the warning is being issued more than once in a row without the user answering the next question.

Writing in one go:

```
"correct"
"correct"
```

Some help?

Answer (score 0):

I think because you are setting `sync` to be `true` and that fires events directly by the stream's subscriptions as they said in the documentation:

> If sync is true, events may be fired directly by the stream's subscriptions during an add, addError or close call.

refer to this link for more info: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/StreamController/StreamController.broadcast.html

hope I could help.

Comment: He even writes twice in the same "shot".

Comment: try setting "sync" to be false or remove it as its default value is false

Comment: The problem continues and I noticed that:

1st shot:
write "correct"

2nd shot:
write "correct" x2 times

3rd shot:
writes "correct" x3 times

and so on.

Comment: We need to see the code for more clarification

Comment: I guess it's because you "add" that to the stream! That is, you add one "correct" every time it's correct. If you answered right, right, wrong, the stream would be "correct", "correct", "false", or whatever you call it... Your listener gets three "events" when the stream is updated. Why not using some other way to print the result, instead of stream? A ChangeNotifierProvider, perhaps? Or change "add" for something else... Is there a "streamController.update()"?